# How do you check in to a campground?

Tags: camping

I am planning a road trip through west coast USA, and am doing camping stops along the way.

I have never reserved a camp ground and have only camped once.

Most of the campgrounds seem to show up on reserveamerica.com.

So if I reserve through this website....how do I check in to the campground?

Are the offices for checking in open late? What happens if I arrive at say 8 to 10pm?

I have no idea what to expect when showing up to a campground that I reserve through reserve america...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most commercial campgrounds have office hours and tend not to be open real late, say 8 or 9pm.

But if you have a reservation and haven't checked in by closing time, they will put a note on the office door telling you which campsite is yours and requesting you to come check in after they open in the morning.

A fair number of campgrounds will allow you to simply choose a campsite, if you arrive without a booking after hours, and then come pay in the morning.  The drawback however is you may not have the passcode to enter the restrooms or showers.

Comment: Good points, although I would add that it's a good idea to call the office and let them know if you plan to arrive late.  That way you can know their precise procedure (and make sure they don't forget to leave info for you, if needed).